# Is there a way to prevent this scroll event firing?

Tags: reactjs

**Context**

I wish to implement an infinite scroll for a chat room.  This means scrolling the bottom message (the most recent) into view when the room loads.

**My Attempted Solution**

Below is pseudo code which represents my attempt.

In short I have an infinite scroll component which will preFill until there is overflow.

The problem is that a scroll event is fired when I call scrollIntoView.  React therefore is doing under the hood which I don't know how to avoid. I've commented the code with "Problem!!" to pin point this problem (within the "Items" component).

Only other option I can think of is to check the timestamp on the event and give the component X time before not returning in the scroll callback.

```
function InfiniteScroll({ children }) {
  const [readyForScrolling, setReadyForScrolling] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (readyForScrolling) {
      let scrollFunc = () => {
        // do scroll stuff
      };

      container.addEventListener('scroll', scrollFunc);
      return () => {
        container.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollFunc);
      };
    }
  });

  // prefill
  useEffect(() => {
    if (checkVarious()) {
      fetchMore();
    } else {
      setPreFillComplete(true);
    }
  });

  return children;
  // pass along props for child as well in real code
}

function Items(items, preFillComplete, setReadyForScrolling) {
  const firstItemRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (preFillComplete) {
      firstItemRef.current.scrollIntoView();
      setReadyForScrolling(true);
      // PROBLEM !!
    }
  });

  return (
    items?.length ?
    items.map((item, i) => (
      <div ref={i == items.length - 1 ? firstItemRef : null}>{item.name}</div>
    ))
  );
}

function List() {
  return (
    <InfiniteScroll>
      <Items />
    </InfiniteScroll>
  );
}
```

**Codepen added**

Here is a codepen.  https://codepen.io/rossm6/pen/abyLMwp

Steps to replicate -

1. Load page and observe in console that "SCROLLING, SCROLLING ... NOOO" is not printed to the console.
2. Uncomment out the line - firstItem.current.scrollIntoView();
3. Reload page.  Notice now that the scrolling comment now prints to the console.

Comment: Did you forget to insert your dependencies in your useEffect hooks or they are without a dependency array?

Comment: No, they are without dependencies

Comment: I don't think is a good approach in general, you are overloading every render with a ton of work, so thinking how dependencies should be structured should be a major concern. Furthermore, it usually brings unexpected behaviors, since you are not controlling directly when hooks should be fired. This makes it difficult to debug your code because we don't know which external state might cause re-renders in your components.

Comment: I ask you two things: please provide `checkVarious()` code and also make explicit the parameters you are passing to Items and how you are saving them in a state

Comment: There isn't a tonne of work to do.  The logic inside the hook determines whether to do the actual work or not.  Besides how else does one add a scroll event listener to an element if not in a useEffect hook without dependencies?  By the way hopefully later I'll have a codepen replicating the issue.

Comment: Remember, use effect hooks are executed always at the first render even when you have a dependency. In your case in particular, since you create the listener only after `readyForScrolling==true`, `readyForScrolling` seems a good dependency. Even more important: the callback you set in an event listener is independent of the hook. This means that the callback is executed even if the hook is not triggered since the hook and the listener are "watching" two different things. The hook is only responsible to link the event to a callback by creating a listener to that event.

Comment: I've added a codepen.  Thanks for advice - I didn't actually know the first point you mentioned so will need to take a look at the react docs again assuming it is mentioned there.  I'll play around now in the pen to see if it works.

Comment: Actually did know that come to think of it.  Still can't get it work with dependencies.  Have you ever worked on implementing an infinite scroll with a prefill capability before?

Comment: Got it to work.  preFillCompleteCallbackWorkDone is now ternary instead of binary.  I just switch the flag first time useEffect is called after scrolling into view.